# These icons are automatically changed like this. How can I remove these and replace original icon? in ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: icons, uninstall, colors, desktop-icons, icon-themes

I want to reset it back to the way it was.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This definitely looks as if you enabled the "High Contrast" accessibility feature (you, not the upgrade). Turn it off again in "Settings" - "Accessibility".

Comment: I did it (my ubuntu is 22.04.3 LTS), but the icons didn't turn back to the original form. Any ideia?